# When coloring listView items using textBox how can i make it to show results on lowercase and uppercase?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If i type in the textBox for example: form1 it will color all the items that contains in the text form1 but if i will type Form1 it will color only some of the items with form1 in the text.

Not sure why since in all the items with form1 in the text it's Form1 with large F
So i don't understand why it's coloring all the Form1 if i type form1 but only part of the items if Form1.

The method i use to color the items.

```
private void ColorListViewItems(Color color, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (textBox4.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        textBox4.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].Text.Contains(textBox4.Text))
                            {
                                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
                            }
                            backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(i * 100 / ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count);
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this one just to color it in black when the textBox is empty

```
private void ColorListViewItems(Color color)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
            }
        }
```

In textBox4 textchanged event

```
private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox4.Text != "")
            {
                if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy)
                {
                    backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
                    ColorListViewItems(Color.Black);
                }
                else
                {
                    ColorListViewItems(Color.Black);
                }
            } 
        }
```

In the dowork progresschanged and completed events

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            ColorListViewItems(Color.Red, e);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged_1(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
```

What i'm trying to do is when i type in textBox4 for example only the letter 'f' or 'F' it will color in Red all the items that the text of the items contains 'f'/'F' and then if i keep typing in the textBox4 the letter 'o' or 'O' it will color now all the items that contains FO and if i keep typing Form1 it should coloring all items contains Form1 or form1 or FoRm1

So each time i type another letter in the textBox4 it's stopping the backgroundworker if it's busy and start it over again.

And if it's empty the textBox4 it will color all the items back to the default color Black.

The problem now is the lowercase and uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this in a case sensitive way? If so, what you have should be the expected results, where items containing "F" are not the same those containing "f".

If you're doing this where `"f" == "F" (should be treated the same)` then why not convert everything to lower?

```
textBox4.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
{
    if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].Text.ToLower().Contains(textBox4.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[i].ForeColor = color;
    }
    backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(i * 100 / ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count);
})
```

I hope I understood your question right.